# How to create a reactive gallery with 3 columns on large screens and 2 columns on mobile?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Essentially, I'm trying to create an image gallery via bootstrap with 3 columns on large screens and 2 columns on mobile. I want to keep the aspect ratio of each image but have a fix width so they align within the columns. I'm a bit of a newbie but I managed to achieve the look on large screens. The issue comes when it's on mobile. While it does follow the intended format, the last column essentially just stacks below the first column. I think I may need to redo my entire approach since I want the images to basically fill up any available space. I have tried other similar posts here but the issue is that their images have similar aspect ratios. The solution may not be bootstrap but I'm not sure exactly where to proceed.

This was my attempt:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="break"></div>
            <h4 class="headline text-center">illustrations.</h4>
            <div class="break"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 fcontainer">
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test3.jpg" alt="Test6">
                </div>
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test4.jpg" alt="Test5">
                </div>
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test6.jpg" alt="Test4">
                </div>
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test1.jpg" alt="Test3">
                </div>
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test5.jpg" alt="Test2">
                </div>
                <div class="row iframe">
                    <img class="item" src="Assets/Illustrations/Test2.jpg" alt="Test1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <--! multiply above div 2 more times for 3 columns -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="break"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-4` for mobile display, and use `col-md-6` for the other large screens display.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#grid-options

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example bd-example-row">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-4 col-md-6">col-sm-4</div>
      
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around to exploring and this is how I achieved what I wanted. Just multiply the gallery-item div multiple times per images in the gallery.

```css
.gallery-container{
    max-width: 86%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.gallery-container .gallery{
    columns: 3;
    gap: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .gallery-container .gallery {
        columns: 2 !important;
    }
}
.gallery-container .gallery img{
    width: 100%;
}
.gallery-item{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is pure `css` not `bootstrap`. hope this helps.If you have any questions comment down below.

```css
html { font-size: 22px; }
body { padding: 1rem; }

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)
}
   
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">ONE</div>
  <div class="card">TWO</div>
  <div class="card">THREE</div>
  <div class="card">FOUR</div>
  <div class="card">FIVE</div>
  <div class="card">SIX</div>
  <div class="card">SEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">EIGHT</div>
  <div class="card">NINE</div>
  <div class="card">TEN</div>
  <div class="card">ELEVEN</div>
  <div class="card">TWELVE</div>
</div>
```

For custom personalization on screen size use `media queries`

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .cards { grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I want but is there a way for me to adjust the property for mobile screens? As it stands, using the code sets each image as a single column. I want to make it so that mobile screens display as 2 columns instead of a singles one. I might have to study it a bit more but I assume this is the part I need to modify?

```grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));```

Comment: you got it right lower the value of 300px.If it didn't work reply me

Comment: I've updated the answer for more granular control. Check that

Comment: This is almost perfect! I modified it to have images and that's the only problem left. The images aren't uniform in size so the columns take up the size of the largest image. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Change `1fr` to a pixel value in `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`